# 'cascading' explode string in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

How to explode this string :

```
00004.00001.00003.00001.00003
```

in an array like this :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '00004' (length=5)
  1 => string '00004.00001' (length=10)
  2 => string '00004.00001.00003' (length=15)
  3 => string '00004.00001.00003.00001.00003' (length=20)
```

Thx

Comment: Do you mean to have 5 elements in the resulting array? It looks like the last element in your array breaks with the pattern you're after.

Comment: `array (size=3)`? Make sure your explanation is right please/

Comment: It's probably some variable dump output, but not that of the commonly used `print_r` or `var_dump`. On topic: This is not so hard to do, what have you tried?

Comment: Explode, then a set of nested `for` loops to concatenate. Good luck with your homework.

Comment: Ho what a beautiful surprise at the wake up :) ok I answer even if I see the solution below :
array (size=3) it's only a mistake a made when I wrote the question.
Thx all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = explode('.', '00004.00001.00003.00001.00003');

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if($array[$key - 1]) {
    $array[$key] = $array[$key - 1] . '.' . $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ceejayoz. This is the solution for my purpose.
`if(!empty($array[$key - 1]))` remove error notice.

Comment: Yeah, some PHP error reporting settings will complain there. You can also do `if(isset($array[$key - 1]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Explode it first as you would normally do `$arr = explode('.', $str);` and then build desired array with two loops.

Answer (score 0):

Another version using array_map() :

```
$arr = explode('.', '00004.00001.00003.00001.00003');
$arr[] = 'blank';
$array = array_map(function(){
     global $arr;
     array_pop($arr);
     return implode($arr);
}, $arr);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But this don't work. Here is the result I get :

`
    array (size=6)  
    0 => string '0000400001000030000100003' (length=25)  
    1 => string '00004000010000300001' (length=20)  
    2 => string '000040000100003' (length=15)  
    3 => string '0000400001' (length=10)  
    4 => string '00004' (length=5)  
    5 => string '' (length=0)  
`